# JavaScript execution path

Tags: javascript

Why `inner()` function gets executed 2 times but not 3?

Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function outer() {

        inner(); 

        function inner() {
            document.write("<p style='background-color:lightblue;'>Inner Function");
        }

        inner(); 
    }

    outer(); 

</script>
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Why would you expect it to be executed three times?

Comment: because you call it 2 times :)

Comment: In order for `inner` to be executed a third time, you'd need to invoke it a third time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see if I can clarify what's going with that code. I believe you're thinking that function definition causes function to be executed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function outer() {

        // call #1
        inner(); 

        // this is the function definition, it is NOT called here
        function inner() {
            document.write("<p style='background-color:lightblue;'>Inner Function");
        } 

        // can #2
        inner(); 
    }

    outer(); 

</script>
```

So as you can see on code comments, function is executed twice, so your results are totally expected